# Syntax error for nested variable in Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible

I have included the below variable file in my playbook:

```
more vars/was_vars.yaml
::::::::::::::
10.9.12.112: "/was/IBM/WebSphere"
10.8.10.28: "/was/IBM/profiles"
10.7.120.129: "/app/tmp"
```

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Configure nodes
  hosts: dest_nodes
  user: "{{ USER }}"
  tasks:
   - name: Construct File Path on "{{ inventory_hostname }}".
     command: "touch {{ BASEPATH }}/{{ ( item | splitext)[1] }}/del.tmp"
     when: "{{ Layer == 'APP' }}"
     file: path="{{ "{{ inventory_hostname }}" }}/{{ App_List }}/{{ Rel_Path }}/del.tmp state=directory mode=u=rwx,g=rw,o=r"
     when: "{{ Layer == 'WAS' }}"
```

"{{ inventory_hostname }}" gets substituted with "10.9.12.112" which should then get further substituted to "/was/IBM/WebSphere" as stated in the included vars("was_vars.yaml") file.

I'm getting the below Syntax error with my current code:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: command, file

The error appears to be in '/app/Ansible/deploy.yml': line 133, column 4, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
   - name: Construct File Path on "{{ inventory_hostname }}".
     ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

I'm on the latest version on ansible.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

1) The dash is missing in front of the *file* module.

2) Nested expansion is not possible (wrong: `"{{ "{{ inventory_hostname }}" }}"`).

3) *when:* condition is expanded by default.

4) The whole string shall be quoted when the expansion of a variable is included.

5) The index of the expansion `{{ ( item | splitext)[1] }}` wont work.

6) It's not clear where do the variable *item* and the filter *splitext* come from.

The correct syntax might be

```
 tasks:

   - name: "Construct File Path on {{ inventory_hostname }}."
     command: "touch {{ BASEPATH }}/{{ item|splitext|first }}/del.tmp"
     when: Layer == 'APP'

   - file:
       path: "{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ App_List }}/{{ Rel_Path }}/del.tmp"
       state: directory
       mode: "u=rwx,g=rw,o=r"
     when: Layer == 'WAS'
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the inputs but what we are actually looking for is how to get the expansion to work...

I.e the inventory_hostname would be substituted with host ip say 10.9.12.112 ... But how do we code to get "/was/IBM/WebSphere" substituted matching the IP from the included variable file?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as :

```
"{{vars[inventory_hostname]}}"
```

or if you want one more level use as :

```
"{{vars[vars[inventory_hostname]]}}"
```